# Visual Basic String encoding conversion (TIS-620 to Big-5)

Tags: character-encoding, vb6

I am new to VB, and I am currently working on a project of visual basic that converts the strings.

I have to convert the Thai characters in TIS-620 to Chinese Big-5.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  However if you have "TIS-620" data you can use an ADO Stream object to convert that (using Charset="windows-874") to Unicode, then convert the Unicode to Big-5 (using Charset="Big5").  Characters that don't map will of course end up as place holders, displayed as "?" symbols usually.

Comment: @Bob77 Um, lets say, I have a file encoded in UTF-8, it contains some Thai characters, when I use Notepadd++ and change the charset, the words become some Chinese words, and that's what i want to achieve. I used the ADO, and tried to change the charset, but then the output became question marks (?)

Comment: UTF-8 is a completely different case.  Perhaps you "see" Thai characters but that's just a misinterpretation of the UTF-8 encoding.  You can convert the UTF-8 to Unicode (UTF-16LE) using ADO.Stream or an API call.  Once you have Unicode you can display it or operate upon it as needed.